# Why does My char array not work?

Tags: c, arrays

I have declared a `char` array in my program to hold 12 characters. I access these values through out the program. But every time I try to run the file it does not give me an error but shows a warning at the char array and the .exe stops executing. My program looks something like this:

```
 int main(){
     char *data[] = {"A,H,H,A"};
     char* ahd_database[12] = {'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D'};

    printf("The first letter in index is %c", index[0]);
```

But this fails to excute. THe warning it gives is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by 
 default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[7]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[6]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[5]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[4]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[3]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[2]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[1]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[0]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[11]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[10]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[9]') [enabled by default]
- (near initialization for 'ahd_database[8]') [enabled by default]
```

Can somebody please point out my mistake?

Comment: what is `ahd_database`????

Comment: In your code, `data` is declared as "_an unbounded array of strings (char*)_" and is initialized with only *one* string, while `ahd_database` is declared as "_an array containing exactly 12 strings (char*)_" though it actually is initialized with 12 characters, which shall trigger a warning. Is this *exactly* what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I have declared a char array in my program to hold 12 characters*

**Nope,** you did not. What you used is array of pointer to `char`, and that is not the same as a `char` array.

In your code, you need to change

```
char* index[12]
```

to

```
char index[12]
```

or, better,

```
char index[ ] = {/*list*/};  //let the compiler allocate the size
```

because, from the initializer-list you supplied, it looks like you want to store `char`s. You don't need an array of `char *`s for that.

*Note: either way, `index` will not be null-terminated, so make sure to use it accordingly. If you want `index` to be used as a **string**, you have to null-terminate it.*

Also, `char *data[] = {"A,H,H,A"};` does not make much sense. A simple `char *data = "A,H,H,A";` will suffice. In case, you want it to be modifiable, `char data[] = "A,H,H,A";` is the option to choose.

Answer (score 2):

```
 char* index[12] = {'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D'};
```

Should be

```
 char index[12] = {'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D'};
 /*  ^                                                                       */
```

As you are trying to print `index[0]` with `%c`, it appears you want the array of `char`s and not `char *`s.

You may also choose to omit the size of `index` array to let compiler fill it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But now after declaring                                char data[]={'A','H','H', 'A'}; when I print out the string 'data' I end up getting an extra garbage value at the end.. Something like this: 'AHHA?'. Could you tell me y do i get the '?' symbol there? :)

Comment: use `char data[] = "AHHA"` or `char data[]={'A','H','H', 'A', '\0'};`. Both are same.

Comment: @MohitJain See, somehow I was expecting this comment (question) to be followed. I was waiting for this as I did update my answer, but this comment _landed_ under your answer. :-)

Comment: @GoldenGirl A string (e.g. a `char*`, when initialized with something between double quotes) is an array of characters, the last of which is implied and is always a zero ("\0") also known as terminating NUL so that string manipulation functions like `printf()` know where the string stops. An array of characters such as `char[]` has no implied terminating NUL *unless explicitly specified*.

Answer (score 2):

The code `char* ahd_database[12] = {'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'D'};` shloud be `char ahd_database[12]=`. Because your initialization is a `char array`, not a `array of char array`. But the code  `char *data[] = {"A,H,H,A"};` is OK, because you have point to a `array of char array`.